# Как проверить тип шаблона на этапе компиляции?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Мне нужно проверить тип шаблона на этапе компиляции. К примеру, я хочу чтоб в качестве шаблонного параметра передавались только типы беззнаковых целых чисел.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename x_Unsigned>
struct
t_MyTemplate
{
    static_assert(::std::is_unsigned_v<x_Unsigned>);
};

t_MyTemplate<unsigned int> x; // ok
//t_MyTemplate<int> x; // error
//t_MyTemplate<float> x; // error
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:34,endLineNumber:12,positionColumn:34,positionLineNumber:12,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:9,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:9),source:%27%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%0Atemplate%3Ctypename+x_Unsigned%3E%0Astruct%0At_MyTemplate%0A%7B%0A++++static_assert(::std::is_unsigned_v%3Cx_Unsigned%3E)%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0At_MyTemplate%3Cunsigned+int%3E+x%3B+//+ok%0A//t_MyTemplate%3Cint%3E+x%3B+//+error%0A//t_MyTemplate%3Cfloat%3E+x%3B+//+error%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g112,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27--std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-Wall+-Wextra+-Wconversion+-Wpedantic+-Werror%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+11.2+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+11.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

С концептами из C++ 20:

```
#include <concepts>

template<::std::unsigned_integral x_Unsigned>
struct
t_MyTemplate
{
};

t_MyTemplate<unsigned int> x; // ok
//t_MyTemplate<int> x; // error
//t_MyTemplate<float> x; // error
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:9,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:9,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:9,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:9),source:%27%23include+%3Cconcepts%3E%0A%0Atemplate%3C::std::unsigned_integral+x_Unsigned%3E%0Astruct%0At_MyTemplate%0A%7B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0At_MyTemplate%3Cunsigned+int%3E+x%3B+//+ok%0A//t_MyTemplate%3Cint%3E+x%3B+//+error%0A//t_MyTemplate%3Cfloat%3E+x%3B+//+error%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g112,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27--std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Wextra+-Wconversion+-Wpedantic+-Werror%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+11.2+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+11.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Comment: Спасибо! Очень полезная инфа!